# Replace div with iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I have a div on a page, like:

```
<div>
   <p>This is a div, but it should be an iframe.</p>
   <p>Here, all kind of stuff could be inside.</p>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>something</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

I want to replace the div with an iframe, to get something like:

```
<iframe>
   <html><body>
   <p>This is a div, but it should be an iframe.</p>
   <p>Here, all kind of stuff could be inside.</p>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>something</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </body></html>
</iframe>
```

How can it be done? A pure javascript-solution would be best, but a solution with jquery of ExtJs would be fine as well.

Comment: ... Why? what's wrong with just having `overflow: auto` on the `<div>`?

Comment: So you have some content on a page and you want to turn it into the *alternative* content for an iframe that has no `src`? (I suspect that isn't the case). Could you clarify what you actually want, and let us know what problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: The problem is I need to apply a completly different css-file to the div than to the rest of the page: The pages css-file shouldn't be valid inside the div and the css-file of the div shouldn't be valid on the page. This can cause problems if you use ExtJs or a Tinymce and mix it up with the css of the page. 

I want to write a generic tool here and don't know how the css of the page if written. I could use the iframe with a src, but that makes loading terrible slow so I thought loading the div with the page and then convert it into an iframe might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var p = {
                onload: function() {
                    var div = document.getElementById("div");
                    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                    iframe.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
                    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="p.onload()">
        <div id="div">
            <p>This is a div, but it should be an iframe.</p>
            <p>Here, all kind of stuff could be inside.</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>something</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It creates the iframe at the end of the document, but it remains empty (only a <html><head></head><body></body></html>). Even using something like: iframe.innerHTML = "<p>It works</p>" seem to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said jQuery solutions are acceptable, how about this:

First, let's assume your div has an id of `remove-my-contents`.

Next, we could do

`$('#remove-my-contents').html('your iframe code goes here');`

It doesn't remove the `<div>` but it does replace its contents with your `<iframe>` code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you really want to replace the entire `<div>` element, use `.replaceWith()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Strange enough, this doesn't have any effect as well:
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.id = "new_iframe";
$('#new_iframe').html('<p>Works</p>');
ends up with an empty iframe (<html><head></head><body></body></html>).

Answer (score -1):

Ah, it seem to be a problem with firefox that the iframe keeps staying empty. See:
[Replace div with iframe in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434569/replace-div-with-iframe-in-javascript)